# Angular2 setinterval

Tags: angular

I use setInterval in angular2 but dont work please help. If i call a function show error. I want to update data of page as ajax and i use setinterval

```
export class AppComponent{ 

  objMonitoring: Monitoring = new Monitoring();
  arrMonitoring: Monitoring[]=[];


  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

  public sampleMethodCall() {
     setInterval(function() {
       this.ngOnInit(); },4000); 
     }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.httpService.getData().subscribe((data: Response) => {
      let monitoringList = data.json();
      this.arrMonitoring = [];   
      for(let index in monitoringList){
        this.arrMonitoring.push(monitoringList[index]);
      }
   });
 }
```

In template i call function this code

```
 <button (click)="sampleMethodCall()">click</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You have an `ngOnInit` method but your class is not implementing it (it isn't necessary but useful).

Your class should look like:

```
import {OnInit} from "@angular/core";

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
...
```

Also your `this` inside the `setInterval` callback is not refering to your page. Use a fat arrow to fix this.

```
setInterval(()=> {
       this.getData(); },4000); 
     }
```

I also really didn't understand why you call `ngOnInit` like that. It's a life-cycle hook. The goal of it is to run after the `constructor` without calling it. That is why you should implement it in your class.

Comment: @aimprogman are you import OnInit class? If yes then it should not give any error.

Answer (score 9):

Basically one difference between anonymous function and arrow function is that arrow function keeps alive the reference of this so if you want to use `this.ngOnInit()` you need to use arrow function as follows:

```
setInterval(()=>{
       this.ngOnInit(); },4000); 
     }


/*setInterval(function() {
       this.ngOnInit(); },4000); //here this referes to the anonymous function
     }*/
```

Comment: function() didn't work for me. Arrow function worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Remove your code from ngoninit() and put that code by creating a new function and call that function in constructor.**

**try below code if setinterval is not working**

setInterval(() => this.Functionname(); },4000);

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is better you use Observable to make poolings. I've some problems with set interval. With Observable you can stop pooling if you want. See the code:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class AppComponent {

objMonitoring: Monitoring = new Monitoring();
arrMonitoring: Monitoring[] = [];

constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

stopPooling = false;
public sampleMethodCall() {
    var timer = Observable.timer(0,5000);
    var self  = this;
    var obj = timer.subscribe(t=>{
        self.getData();
        if(self.stopPooling){obj.unsubscribe();}
    });       
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
}
        private getData(){
            var self  = this;
            this.httpService.getData().subscribe((data: Response) => {
                let monitoringList = data.json();
                this.arrMonitoring = [];   
                for(let index in monitoringList){
                    this.arrMonitoring.push(monitoringList[index]);
                }
            }, (error) => {
                self.stopPooling = true;
            });
        }
```

}

Comment: Why you use this = self ? In Angular 2 isn't necessary. The context is the class no need to use var self = this as is the case angularjs

Comment: well.. i had problems with contexts inside of subscribers in angular2/angular4, so i keep this..

Answer (score 2):

Do you already try this?

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

// Create an Observable that will publish a value on an interval
const secondsCounter = interval(1000);
// Subscribe to begin publishing values
secondsCounter.subscribe(n => {
  console.log(`It's been ${n} seconds since subscribing!`); 
  this.runMyMethod()
});
```

Fore more: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Comment: Thanks i like it compared to using setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with below changes :

```
export class AppComponent{ 

  objMonitoring: Monitoring = new Monitoring();
  arrMonitoring: Monitoring[]=[];


  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

  public sampleMethodCall() {
     let that = this;
     setInterval(() => {
       that.getData(); 
     }, 4000); 
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }

  private getData(){
    this.httpService.getData().subscribe((data: Response) => {
      let monitoringList = data.json();
      this.arrMonitoring = [];   
      for(let index in monitoringList){
        this.arrMonitoring.push(monitoringList[index]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Also you can use [RxJS interval](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/interval.md) instead of `setInterval` method.

Comment: getData is not a function

Comment: i have updated my answer. check it once. you are getting error because inside `setInterval` `this` variable is not refering to component thats the reason with angular 2 `RxJs interval` preferred over `setInterval`

Comment: Using the fat arrow and the  `let that = this` trick is an overkill (they do the same thing). Use only 1 of them.